# Powershell - csv to SQL query

Tags: powershell

I need your help with the following:

I have a .csv file that contains two columns and can contain multiple rows, depending on the data being output to it.

```
number description
------ ------------
1     one
2     two
3     three
```

what I do to read it is with cmdlet import-csv in this way: `$csv=import-csv -path filepath.csv` 
then I pass it to a variable $v=$csv and this is passed to a for to format the number with a defined length `for ($u=0; $u -lt $v.lenght; $u++) $i = $v[$u];`

and finally I pass the data to the connection so that it puts it in a select:

$qry= `"SELECT " + i.ToString() + "AS number" FROM table`
So far so good, it generates the query and exports the results to a different csv file for each line in the "number" column of the csv file.

The problem occurs when the source csv returns a single value, for example '201', which "decomposes" and generates three queries with each number: one with 2, another with 0 and another with 1.

Complete script example:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\path\file.csv" 
$v= $csv;
$dir = "C:\temp\";
    For ($u=0; $u -lt $v.Length; $u++) {
        $i = $v[$u];           
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection    
        $conn.ConnectionString = "ChainConnectionToBD"
        $conn.open()
        $qry = "SELECT " + $i.ToString() +" AS number FROM table";
        $cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($qry,$conn)
        $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        Write-Host  "someText " , $i ,( (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) ) , "rows" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        Write-Host ""
    $conn.close()
    $outputFile1 = $dir + $i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')+"_sometext_"+(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")+".txt";
    $ds.Tables[0] | export-csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path $outputFile1 -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I don't know how to solve it. I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Use a `foreach($i in $v){ ... }` loop instead of `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem a number of ways.

First, by ensuring that `$v` is always an array regardless of how many rows were found in the CSV file:

```
$v = @($csv)
```

---

Another option is to use a `foreach` loop instead - you never use `$u` for anything other than indexing into `$v` anyway:

```
foreach($i in $v){
    # ...
}
```

---

Yet another, similar option, is to pipe the output from `Export-Csv` directly to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv ... |ForEach-Object {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, funcionó perfectamente!